# Changing the File Explorer default unzip location

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, zip

If you download a zipped file to the "**username\Downloads**" folder, and then open it with File Explorer and extract all, the default location is "**username\Downloads**". This is fine and makes sense.

However, if you download a zipped file to "**username\AppData\Local\Temp**" and extract all, it defaults to "**username\Documents**". This is really irritating, so is there any way to change the default extract location? I've tried searching a fair amount, but nothing comes even close.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't you receive a prompt that says `Select a Destination and Extract Files`, along with an associated `Browse...` button?  [Unzip Files from Zipped Folder in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/44101-unzip-files-zipped-folder-windows-10-a.html)

Comment: Yes, it may be a tiny bit trivial, but that's automatically populated with "username\Documents" if the zip is in the temp folder. I want it to be automatically populated with a destination that I choose.

Comment: I am fairly certain [that isn't possible](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/default-extract-location/91186df9-4c5e-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5), but hopefully someone else can help you out a bit more and prove me wrong. If not and you *really* want to avoid clicking that `Browse...` button, you would need to utilize a third-party program like **WinZip** that allows you to [configure a default extract folder](http://kb.winzip.com/help/HELP_DIR.htm).

Comment: @Run5k Yup, theres probably a high chance that it's some sort of hard coded thing, but it is frustrating that it's different for the temp folder.

Comment: I certainly understand how you feel. The possibility to configure a default location seems like it *should* be readily available.  Unfortunately, it isn't.

Comment: It has been several days since we heard from you. Did you have any lingering questions?

Comment: @Run5k nooop it's looking like theres unfortunately not really any way to fix it. It would be interesting to know roughly where in windows this sort of setting is set though, like is it a system32 thing?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I am fairly certain [that isn't possible](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/default-extract-location/91186df9-4c5e-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5). If *really* want to avoid clicking that `Browse...` button, you would need to utilize a third-party program like **WinZip** that allows you to [configure a default extract folder](http://kb.winzip.com/help/HELP_DIR.htm):

> **Extract folder**
>
> These selections determine the default folder that WinZip will use for unzipping.
>
> In the WinZip ribbon, this affects the **Location** field of the Unzip/Share tab; you can override it by clicking the **Location** button.
>
> In the legacy toolbar interface, it sets the initial contents of the Extract to field in the Extract dialog. You can type over this default folder name or select a different folder from the folder list.
>
> - **Open archive folder** - WinZip uses the name of the folder containing the open WinZip file. For example, if c:\download\tools.zip is open, WinZip will use c:\download.
> - **Last extract folder** - WinZip uses the name of the folder you used during the last unzip operation, unless it is on your A: or B: drive. This value is saved when you exit WinZip so you can use it during your next WinZip session.
> - **Folder** - WinZip always uses the specified folder. This value is saved when you exit WinZip so you can use it during your next WinZip session.

[image: WinZip Folder Options]